# incomplete display of the picture plotted by matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I used matplotlib to generate a keyboard. But after I wrote the code, I found that the picture displayed is incomplete. I have tried a few ways to solve the problem, like adjusting the dpi and changing the size of the picture. However, they are all useless.
[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pt2l.png%60fig=plt.figure())

Here is the code:

```
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.set_axis_off()
ax.plot(X,Y)
currentAxis = plt.gca()
generate_keyboard(currentAxis)
plt.text(0,0,"g")
plt.savefig(fname="3.jpg")
plt.show()`

def generate_keyboard(currentAxis):
rect1=patches.Rectangle((-0.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect2=patches.Rectangle((-1.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect3=patches.Rectangle((-2.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect4=patches.Rectangle((-3.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect5=patches.Rectangle((-4.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect6=patches.Rectangle((0.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect7=patches.Rectangle((1.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect8=patches.Rectangle((2.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect9=patches.Rectangle((3.5,-1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect10=patches.Rectangle((-1,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect11=patches.Rectangle((-2,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect12=patches.Rectangle((-3,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect13=patches.Rectangle((-4,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect14=patches.Rectangle((-5,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect15=patches.Rectangle((0,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect16=patches.Rectangle((1,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect17=patches.Rectangle((2,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect18=patches.Rectangle((3,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect19=patches.Rectangle((4,1),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect20=patches.Rectangle((-0.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect21=patches.Rectangle((-1.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect22=patches.Rectangle((-2.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect23=patches.Rectangle((-3.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect24=patches.Rectangle((0.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect25=patches.Rectangle((1.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
rect26=patches.Rectangle((2.5,-3),1,2,linewidth=2,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
currentAxis.add_patch(rect1)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect2)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect3)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect4)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect5)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect6)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect7)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect8)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect9)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect10)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect11)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect12)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect13)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect14)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect15)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect16)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect17)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect18)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect19)currentAxis.add_patch(rect20)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect21)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect22)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect23)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect24)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect25)
currentAxis.add_patch(rect26)
```

Comment: adjust the axes limits with `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves my problem